# How do I calculate the central moment in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to find central moment of an image. The central moment is given by the equation:

[image]

where `x` and `y` are the spatial image co-ordinates, [image] and [image] are the mean `x` and `y` (or centroid) co-ordinates, `p` and `q` being integers and `f(x,y)` is an image.

In addition, I want to understand how to deal with `f(x,y)` because it will be holding all pixel values.

Answer (score 3):

Use `bsxfun`

```
sz = size( img ); %// assuming image is gray scale - 2D array
x = ( 1:sz(2) );
y = ( 1:sz(1) ).'; %'
x = x - mean(x);
y = y - mean(y);
Mpq = sum( reshape( bsxfun( @times, bsxfun( @times, img, x.^p ), y.^q ), [], 1 ) ); %// computing the p-q moment
```

---

benchmarking:

```
disp('Solution of rayryeng')
tic
[rows, cols] = size(img);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
Mpq = sum((X - mean(X)).^p .* (Y - mean(Y)).^q .* img(:));
toc

disp('rayryeng with dot product');
tic
[rows, cols] = size(img);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
Mpq = ((X.' - mean(X)).^p )* ((Y - mean(Y)).^q .* img(:));
toc

disp('this solution - using bsxfun');
tic
sz = size( img ); %// assuming image is gray scale - 2D array
x = ( 1:sz(2) );
y = ( 1:sz(1) ).'; %'
x = x - mean(x);
y = y - mean(y);
Mpq = sum( reshape( bsxfun( @times, bsxfun( @times, img, x.^p ), y.^q ), [], 1 ) );
toc
```

Resulting with

```
Solution of rayryeng
Elapsed time is 0.009426 seconds.
rayryeng with dot product
Elapsed time is 0.008374 seconds.
this solution - using bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.001404 seconds.
```

As you can see `bsxfun` is significantly faster than `meshgrid`-based solutions. Moreover, using dot-product instead of elem-wise product with `sum` is faster.

Comment: Minor note - You should probably mention what `img` contained as well as its size for reproducibility.  I wouldn't mind running this on my machine and seeing the timing comparisons as well.  Another minor note (I'm just nitpicking) would be to mention what computer configuration / architecture you're using, as well as what MATLAB version you're using.  Nice work btw!

Comment: @rayryeng I was using `img = im2double( imread('cameraman.tif'));` its 256-by-256 gray level image.

Answer (score 3):

`f(x,y)` are simply your image intensities at each column location `y` and each row location `x`. If you want to calculate the p-q moment for your image, you can do what [Shai suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27684623/1714410) which will probably be faster.  However, if you want something more readable that doesn't use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun), you can simply do this assuming your image is grayscale and stored in `im`:

```
[rows, cols] = size(im);
im = double(im); %// For precision
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);
Mpq = sum((X - mean(X)).^p .* (Y - mean(Y)).^q .* im(:));
```

First we convert the image to `double` to ensure that we get the best precision possible.  Your image will probably be of type `uint8`, and any values computed that exceed 255 will be clipped.  You will probably get values beyond this and so casting to `double` is recommended.  We then use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate a grid of spatial co-ordinates with the same size of the image, then unroll the co-ordinates to a single vector.   This will make it easier to compute the moment.  The last line of code finally computes our moment as per the equation.  We also need to unroll the image in the same fashion so that the elements line up properly.

Comment: @Shai - I never said my approach was better!  I did say that `bsxfun` is much faster.  I wrote something else that may be easier to understand if the OP isn't used to `bsxfun`.  I would always choose `bsxfun` every time.  FWIW, it took me a while to understand how `bsxfun` worked and for a novice MATLAB programmer, `bsxfun` may be a bit difficult to get used to.

Comment: sorry. please see my comment about using dot-product instead of elem-wise product coupled with `sum`.

Comment: @Shai - Thank you.  I always forget that using the dot product approach is much faster in a vectorized manner.  Thank you for benchmarking :)